# Не могу избавиться от мерцания курсора в окне Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

[Я просил помощи на форуме notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/16840/the-strange-behavior-of-the-cursor-in-the-notepad-window) но там никто не сталкиваться с подобным, а сам автор программы мочит на эту тему.
У меня семерка 32-битная, вирусов нет, система не загаженная, notepad++ обновил до последней версии. Это уже продолжается очень давно и на всех версиях notepad++. Перезагрузишь notepad++ и все пропадает мерцания, а потом опять появляется это косяк. Ось за насколько лет переустанавливалась и notepad++ обновлялся, проблема все равно так и осталась.

[image: Вот примерно так это все выглядит]

Comment: Проверьте на «чистой» установке N++

Comment: В смысле на "чистой установке"? Новая версия вышла неделю назад, все установлено с нуля, я использую только портативную версию (и она от автора программы )

Comment: Попробуйте вычистить все в реестре что связано с Н++

Comment: Выглядит как будто бы XP какакя-то... Может несовместимость с темой оформления винды.

Comment: Это оригинальная семерка и стандартная классическая тема. Мне так больше нравиться. Какая из тем стоит не имеет значения, эта галлюцинация все равно периодически будет играть! Я уже голову сломал не знаю в какую сторону думать. Уже надоело постоянно перегружать этот блокнот.

Comment: Как вы понимаете, есть только два варианта. Первый — какой-то глюк на уровне N++. Это может быть что-то связанное с настройками или его плагинами. Если бы проблема была у всех, то наверное об этом уже знали. Второй — что-то на уровне системы. Это оформление, программы и т.д. Тут вам никто не поможет, придется искать самому.

Comment: Я на форуме общался с одним китайцем, он мне примерно тоже самое говорит. Но вот это и проблема ...как определить где эта собака зарыта?

Comment: Ну как минимум переключитесь на дефолтную тему виндовс, возможно на этом уровне конфликт. Дальше уже смотрите какие программы ещё запущены, вдруг что-то из них так влияет...

Comment: Сброс темы по умолчанию ничего не меняет. Вчера переустановил ось на 7х64про, до этого была 7х32 Хом Премиум. Посмотрю что измениться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поднял эту тему там на GitHub [Blinking cursor in Notepad++ #5529](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/5529).
Автор программы Notepad++ наконец нашел эту ошибку и [исправил ее](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/commit/b2191e9e6f5ad82774ff6dac589e8da9c5ff8091).

Comment: Как вам стало это известно? Добавте в ответ (ссылка или цитата).

Comment: Так я сам поднял эту тему там на форуме, правда все с места сдвинусь только со второго захода. https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/5529